# How do you handling floating point arithmetic when using the ParseObject.increment() function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In javascript, we know that some floating point arithmetic will result in values that contain a very small remainder. for example if I open my console and do this math I get this result as seen here

[image]

Typically one must know to round after doing these operations. When using parse, and using the `increment` function. If I have a column called Quantity in my DB and it currently has a value of 6.5 and I call `myobject.increment("Quantity", -4.1)` we end up with an unrounded value in the DB. the use of increment is required here as many entities may be adjusting this column at or near the same time, so race conditions are a concern.

since the arithmetic happens under the hood, how does parse expect one to handle cases like I mentioned above.

Comment: How many significant digits do you want? `Math.round` will truncate all the way to an integer.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think I follow can you show me how one would use the parse `increment` function in conjunction with `Math.round` I think the issue is that the math happens inside of the increment function which is a part of parse-platform

Answer (score 0):

You may do one of two:

1. Change the logic inside `increment` function.
2. Do increment outside and use some setter.

Anyway in case you want to prevent non exact values, you should round it manually. [Look here for number rounding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Comment: does parse really not offer and out of the box solution for this?